# Centering a button in Wordpresss

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress and the PopUp Maker plugin.

I try to center the 'DOWNLOAD NOW' button, but unsuccessfully.

I should probably use a CSS code but have no idea what to do with it.

Any idea how to fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The css you need is the following:

```
.pum-container .pum-content button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The pum-container and pum-content should be the fitting class for the popup maker plugin.

Add these lines of code to your functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');
function theme_enqueue_styles()
{
    wp_register_style(THEME_NAME . '-style', THEME_PATH . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style(THEME_NAME . '-style');
}
```

Then add a file called style.css on the same level as your functions.php and add in the css lines from above